# Python scapy - script cant stop after reading PCAP using rdpcap()

Tags: python, pcap, scapy

I am reading **PCAP** file using python scapy library like this:

```
pkts = rdpcap(filename)
```

But my script cant stop. I try call `sys.exit()` at the end of my script but nothing happened. Script is always running.

Comment: I doubt the cause is the `rdpcap` call. Can you post the content of the script (if it's complicated, create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Does the script stop when hitting `Ctrl-C`? If so, what is the stack trace?

Comment: Yeah after Ctrl+C it stops. But if i comment the line pkts = rdpcap(filename), the script ends properly.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily mean that the problem is with the line `pkts = rdpcap(filename)`. Perhaps it has something to do with your handling of `pkts` following that line. Anyway, please post the content of the script (if it's complicated, create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, post the stack trace that is generated when hitting `Ctrl-C`.